# In Solr, how can we use terms external to the search query to bias result ordering?

Tags: solr, solrnet

We're working on a plan to identify content tags our users are interested in.  So, for instance, we may determine that User X consumes content tagged with "kermit" and "piggy" more often than other tags. These are their "favored tags."

When the users search, we'd like to favor/bias documents that contain these terms.

This means we can't boost the documents at index time, because every user will have different favored tags.  Additionally, *they may not be searching for the favored tags themselves*.  They may search for "gonzo," and so we absolutely want to give them documents with "gonzo," but we want to boost documents that *also* contain "kermit" or "piggy."

These favored tags are not used to actually query the index, but rather are used to bias the result ordering.  The favored tags become something of a tie-breaker -- all else being equal, documents containing these terms will rank higher.

This is new/planned development, so we can use whatever version and parser stack is optimal to solve this problem.

**Solution in SolrNet**

The question was correctly answered below, but here's the code for SolrNet just in case someone else is using it.

```
var localParams = new LocalParams();
localParams.Add("bq", "kermit^10000); //numeric value is the degree of boost

var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<MySolrDocumentClass>>();
solr.Query(new SolrQuery("whatever") + localParams);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify which query parser you're using, but if you are using the [Dismax](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser) or [Extended Dismax](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Extended+DisMax+Query+Parser) query parser, the `bq` argument should do exactly what you're looking for. `bq` adds search criteria to a search solely for the purpose of affecting the relevancy, but not to limit the result set.

From the [Dismax](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser) documentation:

> **The bq (Boost Query) Parameter**
>
> The bq parameter specifies an additional, optional, query clause that
>   will be added to the user's main query to influence the score. For
>   example, if you wanted to add a relevancy boost for recent documents:
>
> ```
> q=cheese 
> bq=date:[NOW/DAY-1YEAR TO NOW/DAY]
> ```
>
> You can specify multiple bq parameters. If you want your query to be
>   parsed as separate clauses with separate boosts, use multiple bq
>   parameters.

In this case, you may want to add `&bq=kermit&bq=piggy` to the end of your Solr query. If you aren't using one of these query parsers, this need may be exactly the motivation you need to switch.

Comment: Again, this is new development, so we can use whatever we like.  But this bf param -- this doesn't affect the query itself, correct?  It just affects the ordering of the results that would have been returned anyway?

Comment: Correct. As it says in the example given in the documentation, the `bq` query is giving a **relevancy boost** to recent documents. If the same search were part of the default `q` search or a filter query `fq`, then _only_ recent documents would be returned. With `bf`, the only thing affected is the document `score`, which affects the order of the results whenever you are sorting by `score` (which I assume you're doing).

Comment: I tested this, and you are correct. "bf" does not change the returned values, it just biases them based on the existence of a term.  Nicely done.

Comment: I need clarification -- is it "bf" or "bq"?  Both are valid.  I was testing with "bq" and it worked.

Comment: In fact, with "bf", Solr returned an error: Undefined Field "kermit".  "bf" is "boost function," not "boost query," which means it's looking for a function specification or a field:value specification, I think.  Did you mean "bq"?

Comment: Yes, I did. I pulled in the docs for `bq`, but mistyped and entered the wrong thing elsewhere. Sorry about that!